# call a webservice with list<int> as paramter from jquery .ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice with webmethod that looks like:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Gets places by Category & City")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public List<P> GetCitiesPs(int CategoryId,list<int> CityIds)
{
   return MyManager.GetPs(CategoryId, CityIds);
}
```

the parameter CityIds is a list of values of checked checkboxes.

```
 var CityIds = new Array(); 
$('.City-checkbox').each(function() {
            Checked = $(this).attr('checked');
            if (Checked == true) {
                CityId = $(this).attr('value');
                CityIds.push(CityId);
            }

        });
```

now when i call the webservice method with .ajax,but it doesn't fire.

```
var Params = JSON.stringify({ 'CategoryId': CategoryId, 'CityIds': CityIds });
    alert(Params);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FinKaynWebService.asmx/GetCitiesPs",
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
        },
        failure: function(msg) {
            alert('somethin went wrong' + msg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of passing List<int> you can pass comma separated string from client side and then you can parse it easily on server side.

Comment: Thanks,that 's what i used.It works.Thanks a lot.How can i pass this question to answered.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the $.post function instead

```
$.post(URL-TO-POST-TO, { DATA-TO-POST }, function() {
    // callback code
}, 'json');
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/